# How to write promises and connections while executing multiple Mysql queries in Nodejs?

Tags: mysql, node.js, promise, dbconnection

How can I use multiple queries while constructing promises.
Below is the example code of context.

```
const mysql = require('mysql');
 
const pool = mysql.createPool({
    connectionLimit: 10,    
    password: “yourDBpassword”,
    user: “yourusername”,
    database: “yourDBname”,
    host: “locahost”,
    port: “yourDBport”
 
}); 
SelectAllElements = () =>{
    return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
        pool.query('SELECT * FROM DB_table ',  (error, elements)=>{
            if(error){
                return reject(error);
            }
            return resolve(elements);
        });
    });
};
```

Also, do I need to write db.getconnection everytime I write query functions?  Is it possible to end connection without using constructor as it's done below?

```
const mysql = require( 'mysql' );
class Database {
    constructor( config ) {
        this.connection = mysql.createConnection( config );
    }
    query( sql, args ) {
        return new Promise( ( resolve, reject ) => {
            this.connection.query( sql, args, ( err, rows ) => {
                if ( err )
                    return reject( err );
                resolve( rows );
            } );
        } );
    }
    close() {
        return new Promise( ( resolve, reject ) => {
            this.connection.end( err => {
                if ( err )
                    return reject( err );
                resolve();
            } );
        } );
    }
}
```

Comment: I wrote this in response to questions around structuring mysql code in node. I think it answers your questions. Hope it's helpful: https://evertpot.com/executing-a-mysql-query-in-nodejs/

Comment: @Evert Thank you for your answer. I have 15/20 queries for counting different rows. Is it ok to accumulate that many queries in one connection?

Comment: Doing everything (1 at a time, serialized) in 1 connection is a good default. Only when you start using *many* connections things start getting a little risky and there's a number of pitfalls with this.

Comment: So if you have 1 big HTTP request and need to do a number of queries, start with 1 connection and if that's too slow you could decide to parallelize *some* of these in separate connections.

Comment: What is the risk of using db.getConnection before every query and then using connection.release() function after finishing each call?

Comment: Let me turn that around, why use a new connection for every call?

Comment: As far as I know mysql DB query needs to open the connection before it makes query. I might be wrong too. I have been trying to use promise for many queries but couldn't comprehend the idea yet.

Comment: No, a connection gets made once and then it can be used for *many* queries as long as you do them one at a time. It's expensive to make an new connection, so this is an optimization and why the pool actually keeps its connections open for re-use.

Comment: Thank you so much. One more thing! Do I need to use util.promisify() if I use mysql2/promise package and create pool with it?

Comment: If you use `mysql2/promise` it already uses promises, so no.